# build.gradle Error:(57, 0) No such property sourceFile for class: org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy_Decorated?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, robotium, build.gradle

I am using robotium to test my app but when i Updated android studio 1.0.2 build.gradle Error:(57, 0) No such property sourceFile for class: org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy_Decorated

As log says Error is in the copyTask sourceFile
any one

```
 buildscript {
repositories {

    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+'
}
}

 apply plugin: 'android'
 repositories {
 mavenCentral()
 flatDir {
    dirs 'libs'
}
}

dependencies {
androidTestCompile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 'android-19'
buildToolsVersion '19.1'

android {
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    sourceSets
            {
                androidTest
                        {
                            res.srcDirs = ['res']
                            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
                        }
            }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
    }
}
}
task assembleDebug(overwrite: true) {}

task copyTask (type: Copy) {
sourceFile = 'C:/Users/Shivam/Desktop/abc/Apks/ansd.apk'
destDir    = 'build/outputs/apk/'
destName   = 'RecorderApplicationTest-debug.apk'

from sourceFile
into destDir

rename {
    destName
}
}

assembleDebug.dependsOn copyTask
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `def` for used properties at `copyTask`

```
def sourceFile = 'C:/Users/Shivam/Desktop/abc/Apks/ansd.apk'
def destDir    = 'build/outputs/apk/'
def destName   = 'RecorderApplicationTest-debug.apk'
```

Comment: In new gradle "runProguard()" is replaced by "minifyEnabled".  When i tried as you said it says, Error:(16, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'Robotium' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="openGradleSettings">Gradle settings</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>

Comment: @Shivaraj2 please provide full `build.gradle` to see what is the problem

Comment: it's not clear what error about "Error (16, 0)" which is line ?

Comment: inside buildTypes line "minifyEnabled false" gives  //Error(16,0)

Answer (score 0):

Please update Robotium Recorder. This is an issue that was fixed some time ago.

Comment: can you please give me the link to download latest robotium.jar currently i am using robotium-solo-5.2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar